# Exclude a nested directory from being copied over when using a src glob

Tags: gulp, glob, minimatch

I can't exclude a directory structure from being copied over when using a glob in gulp src method. My task:

```
gulp.task( 'compile', function () {
    return gulp.src( 'src/modules/*/wrappers/**' )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'build/' ) );
} );
```

I am expecting to copy only files, not whole dir structure.

**My dir structure:**

```
+ src/
  + modules/
      + module_1/
          + wrappers/
              file_1
              file_2
      + module_2/
          + wrappers/
              file_3
              file_4
+ build/
```

**Dir structure after running gulp task:**

```
+ src/
  + modules/
      + module_1/
          + wrappers/
              file_1
              file_2
      + module_2/
          + wrappers/
              file_3
              file_4
+ build/
  + modules/
      + module_1/
          + wrappers/
              file_1
              file_2
      + module_2/
          + wrappers/
              file_3
              file_4
```

**Expected dir structure after running gulp task:**

```
+ src/
  + modules/
      + module_1/
          + wrappers/
              file_1
              file_2
      + module_2/
          + wrappers/
              file_3
              file_4
+ build/
      file_1
      file_2
      file_3
      file_4
```

**It's worth noting that using e.g. glob 'src/modules/module_1/wrappers/**' gives desired result.**

Used modules:

- gulp 3.8.10

Am I doing something wrong or is that bug in js glob implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong; gulp stores files with it's relative paths, which is why you're getting the whole directory structure.

You could use [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten):

```
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
gulp.task( 'compile', function () {
    return gulp.src( 'src/modules/*/wrappers/**' )
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'build/' ) );
} );
```

Comment: Hello Nickm thaks for response. That's very interesting module - will try in in no time. 

It can temporary solve issue but its not giving any answer why my problem is happening. If "relative paths" were behind this issue then globe "src/modules/module_1/wrappers/**" would generate same result - but its working fine.

Additionally as far as I understand globe with e.g. construction "wrappers/**" should match paths to files & subdirectories inside dir "wrappers" & nothing outside (check in terminal command "ls wrappers/**" ).